# I'm trying to build a random chat app using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create an app where only two people join a random chatroom send each other some messages and are then exited from that chatroom and put into a new one.

Only problem is I don't understand how to just limit it to two people.

Below is my chatroom code.

```
struct Chatroom: Codable, Identifiable {

    var id: String
    var title: String
    var joinCode: Int }


class ChatRoomModel: ObservableObject  {
    
    @Published var joiningCode = Int.random(in: 1...99)
    @Published var chatrooms = [Chatroom]()
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    private let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    @Published var newTitle = ""
    @Published var isOpen = false
        
    func createChatroom(title: String, handler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        if (user != nil) {
            
        db.collection("Chatrooms").document(user!.email!).setData(["title": title,
                                                                   "joinCode": joiningCode,
                                                                    "users": [user!.uid]]) { err in
        if let err = err {
                      
        print("error adding document! \(err)")
                              
        } else {
        print("Chatroom Created!")
        handler()
            
            }
        }
    }}
    
        func joinChatroom(handler: @escaping () -> Void) {
                                            
db.collection("Chatrooms").whereField("joinCode", isEqualTo: Int(joiningCode)).getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
            
    if error != nil {
        debugPrint("Couldn't Join!")
        self.createChatroom(title: self.newTitle, handler: {self.isOpen = true})
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                self.db.collection("Chatrooms").document(document.documentID).updateData(["users": FieldValue.arrayUnion([self.user!.uid])])
                         print("Chatroom Joined!")
                handler()
        }
    }
}}
    
    func deleteChatroom() {
                        
        let docRef = db.collection("Chatrooms").document(user!.email!)
        docRef.delete(completion: { err in
            
        if err != nil {
                
        print("Something wrong!")
                
        } else {
            
        print("Deleted Chatroom!")
            
            }
        })
    }
```

And here are my firebase rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow write;
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

I hope the rules are fine, but I get told by firebase that they're insecure.

Comment: What exact line in the code you shared isn't doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: This line - self.createChatroom(title: self.newTitle, handler: {self.isOpen = true}). I want to be able to create a new chatroom with a particular code incase one doesn't already exist but my create chatroom function doesn't run when such a chatroom doesn't already exist.

Comment: The `createChatroom` is a function you created. If you step through that function in a debugger, and check the values of all variables on each line, which API call to Firebase doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Off topic but using a users email as a documentId is usually a bad idea. Emails change and if that happens, you won't know who that chat belongs to. Better bet is use the users uid as the documentId, or some other data that won't change; perhaps event an auto-created documentId would work.

Comment: Yeah I was gonna use an auto documentId, but I don't know how to delete that once I'm done using it since the id generated is random. How is it possible to reference that in my deletechatroom function?

Comment: There's a bunch of ways, but using the users uid as the documentId is pretty easy. If not, then another option is to store the chats the user is involved in in a /users/uid/chats collection within the users document. That way when the user logs in, that document can be read and all of the chats they are involved in can be observed. Likewise you can get their chats via a query of the chats collection for any that contain the user id. We don't know at what point the chat would be deleted but if, in your ui, you're showing a list of chats, the documentId would have already been loaded.

Comment: I see, thank you for your holistic replies. I've considered using the uid since that seems much simpler, would you happen to know if it is possible to create a chat interface using firebase where two random users join a chatroom and after sending a few messages they are then shifted to a different chatroom. I've realised how to create and delete chatrooms using various codes but what I'm not able to understand is how to make sure that only two users join it at a time and no more than that. The chatroom is a document that the user joins or creates if one doesn't exist already.

Comment: When replying in chat, get that person name with an @ sign, like @Jay. Yes, it is possible, and there are 100 different ways to accomplish that. Once simple solution is, that when a third user attempts to join a chat, query the chat document/collection/whatever, count the number of returned elements and if it's less then 2 then allow the join. Alternately, if you have a master collection of ongoing chats, you could keep the count of the number of users in each in that collection and simply read the number if a third users is attempting to  join. Again, there are 98 more options.

Comment: Wow @Jay you've really helpful, thank you for all your replies. Now I can finally finish making my app thanks to you!